# rails asset precompile error when less-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less

I was doing rake assets:precompile and found this error:

```
rake aborted!
error evaluating function asset-url: method `method_missing' called on terminated object (0x007fe94f714518 flags=0x0 klass=0x0)
(in /Users/huming/work/strikingly/Bobcat/app/assets/stylesheets/themes/bright/main.less)
at less.Parser.parser.parse.i (/Users/huming/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@bobcat/gems/less-2.3.3/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js:421:31)
```

I was using less-rails-2.3.2; and I also tried less-rails-2.4.2, and it doesn't work too.
Any idea how this happens?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing but it seems to be intermittent. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @DrewB not yet, still looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by an issue with how weak references work in Ruby 1.9.3, causing them to be garbage collected too soon. Then when attempting to use a garbage-collected object, Ruby understandably crashes. I also experience it intermittently.

> [S]adly, there is no easy fix due to fundamental defects in the WeakRef implementation on 1.9.3
>
> There may be a more solid workaround, than what the ref gem provides, but I personally don't have the bandwidth to make this a priority given that it works on rubinius and MRI 2.0

https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/176#issuecomment-20147324

Below is an example of it being worked around in code by explicitly marking something not to be garbage collected too soon:

```
-      params[i] = sqlite3val2rb(argv[i]);
+      VALUE param = sqlite3val2rb(argv[i]);
+      RB_GC_GUARD(param);
+      params[i] = param;
```

https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/60